# Understanding numberForPlot: and numberOfRecordsForPlot: Core Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, core-plot

I'm implementing a bar graph and am having issues understanding the two method `numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` and `numberOfRecordsForPlot`

I currently have

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return 4;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {
    switch (idx) {
        case 0:
            return @1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return @2;
            break;
        case 2:
            return @3;
            break;
        case 3:
            return @4;
            break;
        default:
            return @0;
            break;
    }
}
```

which makes a graph as expected. When I change say the `@4` to `@5` it displays the last bar with an empty bar space next to it. This makes sense if I'm plotting both the x and y position for each of the 4 entries according to `numberOfRecordsForPlot` but when I log the information in `numberForPlot` it only has 0 & 1 for the fieldEnum.

I've looked at the doco and examples and is no clearer to me. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that the `fieldEnum` of that delegate method is not doing what you think. It will either have the value of `CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation` (the 'x' axis location) or `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip` (the bar height), so these should be the cases used in the switch statement. The `idx` refers to the specific bar.

Here I have put the heights of the bars in a property of the data source object called `plotData`.

```
self.plotData = @[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(4)];
```

Then you can implement the delegate method like this,

```
-(NSNumber*) numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            return @(idx);
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            return [plotData objectAtIndex:idx];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```